# Format html text in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React library and I want to insert a text with `<br>` text inside a html element.

```
var FinancialOverviewRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
            <tr>
                {
                    this.props.data.map(function(val, index) {
                        jsx = <div>{val}</div>;
                        return (<td className={fields[index].classname} key={key}>
                                    {jsx}
                        </td>);
                    })
                }
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

But here the `val` is a text which sometimes includes `<br>` . How can I format it somehow that I really use this tag as a HTML tag ? 
All the solutions I've seen somehow use jQuery which I don't.

Comment: if all you're trying to do is break the line. `\n` at the end of your string should work ex `var string = "Hello\nWorld";`

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+html+string

Comment: @mwilson no it doesn't work, because it gets rendered into DOM element and `\n` means nothing in HTML.